# Finding all ancestors until node id

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a Node Tree i like to iterate to find all ancestors until a given point (node) in the tree.
That way i can inserted/save it back to my db.
So far i have something like the following which has been proven very useful, so far:

```
public IEnumerable<INode> Ancestors()
{
   var parent = this.Parent;
   while (parent != null)
   {
      yield return parent;
      parent = parent.Parent;
   }
}
```

I think, I should be passing a Func or Func in order to stop/break the sequence.

What would it be the best implementation?.Ta

Edited: Given the answers below. Im thinking going for something more performant like:

```
 public IEnumerable<INode> Ancestors(Func<INode, bool> predicate)
 {
    var parent = this.Parent;
    while (parent != null)
    {
      if (predicate(parent))
      { 
         yield return parent;
      }
      else
      { 
         yield break; 
      }

      parent = parent.Parent;
    }
 }
```

Am i right saying Jon's answer will create 2 enumerators?

Comment: do you want a range? Like get all until id=X? which might retrun 15 items if id starts at 1 and X = 15

Comment: yeah thats the gist!, but it can be any, an Id or any predicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
var desiredNode = child.Ancestors().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Id == desiredId);
```

That give `null` if the right node can't be found.

EDIT: Okay, if you need the complete sequence from bottom to top, you can just use:

```
var nodes = child.Ancestors().TakeUntil(node => node.Id == desiredId);
```

where `TakeUntil` is a method like `TakeWhile` but which includes the final node which matched the predicate. You can find a [sample implementation](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs) in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com). If you don't mind the lack of argument validation (which MoreLINQ *does* provide), it's very simple to write:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeUntil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                          Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

You *could* build the functionality into the `Ancestors()` method, but it's mixing two responsibilities into one relatively-complex function, instead of having two simple functions which can be composed with other simple functions in a very general way.

Comment: I need the whole sequence, bottom to top and stop in the ID

Comment: must say..Im chuffed Mr Skeet answered my very first question in SO. Thanks and keep it up.

Comment: Actually..., how will the two queries execute. all at once or it will loop twice?. This is an operation i intend to use quite a lot. As a matter of fact will probably live in a Entity object. although i love the extension method, too. i think gilly's answer might be more performant which in this case primes.

Comment: @ErMasca: It streams - it's not going to copy everything into a list or anything like that. Think of your Ancestors() method as maintaining a cursor of the current position. It yields a value to TakeUntil, which then decides whether or not to yield it to the caller. It sounds like you could do with reading my Edulinq blog series :) http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx (This isn't quite LINQ, but it's the same ideas...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<INode> Ancestors(Func<INode, bool> takeUntil)
{
   var parent = this.Parent;
   while (parent != null)
   {
      yield return parent;
      if (takeUntil(parent))
      {
         break;
      }
      parent = parent.Parent;
   }
}
...
var ancestors = node.Ancestors(n => n.Id == 123);
```

Comment: I think it's cleaner to separate the "take until" behaviour from the "find ancestors" behaviour. Composition rocks :)